# How to describe mathematically connections of vertexes in a DAG

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

My question is how could I improve the way that I am describing the connections of the arcs? I would like to describe more mathematically. Any example would help. Bellow is a short example to show how I am representing.

Arcs are of two types:

- Arcs that corresponds to routing constraints. 
  There is an arc between $s$ and all the initial operations of job $J_j$ of length $r_j$;
  an arc between operations $O_{i,j}$ and operation $O_{i',j}$ of length $p_{i,j,k}$ if a routing constraint imposes that $O_{i,j}$ has to precede $O_{i',j}$.
- Arcs that corresponds to resource constraints. If operation $O_{i,j}$ precedes operation $O_{i',j'}$ on $M_k,$ there is an arc between $O_{i,j}$ and $O_{i',j'}$ of length $x$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two descriptions seem just fine, although I'd generally avoid the use of primes in subscripts, so I'd say "between operations $O_{i,j}$ and $O_{s, t}$," or something like that.

The problem is that this is the *modeling* part of the process, where you try to associate something in the real world, like jobs and processes, to something mathematical, like a DAG. The "glue" is your writing, and you seem to have done OK here. But it's bound to be the messiest part in almost any such task.